# Skull size of Homo naledi

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy

I want to 3D print the skull of the newly discovered [*Homo naledi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_naledi).

The printing data can be found here: http://morphosource.org/index.php/Detail/MediaDetail/Show/media_id/7300

Where can I find the exact size of the skull so that I get a 1:1 copy? Google was of no help.

Comment: To 3-d print it, you need the volume right , not the area cause I know the volume

Comment: @Tusky: I think this would be helpful!

Comment: From the link:a cranial volume of 560 cm3 (34 cu in) for the males and 465 cm3 (28.4 cu in) for females, approximately half the volume of modern human skulls; average Homo erectus skulls are 900 cm3 (55 cu in). You could use these data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Figure 11 in the original publication (scale bar = 10 cm):

[image]

The anteroposterior length of the skull should be about 16.3 cm. I just printed out the figure and did the conversion.

So check that your 3D printing software estimates a little over 16 cm for the length from brow ridge to occipital. The full reconstructed skull will be longer of course, but this should give you a concrete measurement to compare to.

Comment: Yowza! That's quite the brow! Guess no hats for *H. naledi*!

Answer (score 1):

From my research, I can deduce that the cranial volume for males is

> ***560 cm3 (34 cu in)***

and

> ***465 cm3 (28.4 cu in) for females***

Note: These skulls are approximately half the volume of modern human skulls average Homo erectus skulls are

> ***900 cm3 (55 cu in)***

I don't think you would need the area for 3-D printing, but you can use the volume!

Comment: From your research? It's in my comment :)

Comment: @Christiaan It was in the wiki link. I did some reading thats all